# Inverse of exponential integral function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions

The exponential integral function $x \mapsto E_1(x)$ is strictly decreasing on the positive real
axis and, so, is globally real analytically invertible there.  Where can I find information concerning
a maximal domain in the complex plane over which $E_1$ possesses a holomorphic global inverse that continues the real one?

Answer (score 2):

Just two remarks: a) it is simply related with the integral logarithm,
$$\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{e^t}{t}dt=\int_0^{e^x}\frac{dt}{\log t},$$
which is a better known function. b) There is a whole book on it:

Niels Nielsen, Theorie des Integrallogarithmus und verwandter Transzendenten. 37.0454.01
Leipzig: B. G. Teubner. VI u. 104 S. (1906).

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark: for all your elementary needs regarding special functions, the one-stop shop is the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/).

There is an [index](https://dlmf.nist.gov/idx/), and you find what you are looking for [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#i).

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  But while it confirms that $E_1$ itself continues onto a slit

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  But while it confirms that $E_1$ itself continues well-definedly onto a slit region, it seems to say nothing about continuing the inverse off of the image of the positive real axis.  For instance, might $E_1$ actually be one-to-one on that slit domain?  (Sorry about the botched comment just above.)